# Holes in washer basket

Tags: appliances, washing-machine

I recently removed the agitator in my Whirlpool (model LSQ8500JQ1) washer to replace the "dogs". The bottom of the basket looked like this:
[image]

Something is missing in the upper hole, what is it and should I be worried about it? Thanks...

Comment: Possibly a rubber grommet a clearer close up might help.

Comment: I would suspect that the agitators sit on those grommets and that helps keep them from rattling. While it's probably not critical to the operation of the washer, without the grommet, the tub _will_ be unbalanced. I'd suspect that the grommet is either stuck to the bottom of one of the agitator arms, or is in the bottom of the washer cabinet. Either that, or it's partying with all the lost socks...

Comment: Grommet - thanks. Wherever it is it is long gone. I'll check with the appliance store if they ever open up here again.

Comment: order online: eg https://www.searspartsdirect.com/model/20oggpbz1v-001198/whirlpool-lsq8500jq1-washer-parts